# display the progress of a treatment in a textarea with Python Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have in my html file a button and a textarea. When I click on the button the treatment below starts. I want to display in the textarea the progress of this treatment. I want to be able to choose when and where in my processing the data to be displayed is sent.

Here my views.py

```
@matrices.route("/generer_matrices", methods=['POST'])
def generer_matrices():
    try:
        #Send('Start')
        u = 0

        u= u +1
        #......
        #Send(str(u))

        u= u +2
        #.....

        #Send('End')

    except Exception as e:
        #Send('Error')
        print(e)
    return ""
```